How add a cache context in a form_alter?
I'm on Drupal 10.2.x.
I'm writing a form_alter for a node add/edit form, where I am putting some extra markup data depending on terms of a vocabulary licenses.
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if(//checks to execute code only for the right form) {
    $licenses = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
      ->loadTree('licenses', 0, NULL, TRUE);
    $build = [];
    foreach ($licenses as $license) {
     $build[$license->id()]['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'div',
        '#value' => $license->getName(),
      ]; 
      // add other elements to $build
     }
    $form['field_license']['#suffix'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')
      ->renderPlain($build);
 }
}

If I try to add the relative cache context, taxonomy_term_list:licenses, either doing:
 $form['#cache']['contexts'] = Cache::mergeContexts( $form['#cache']['contexts'], ['taxonomy_term_list:licenses']);

or
$form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'taxonomy_term_list:licenses';

I get the error

The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.


AssertionError: Failed to assert that "languages:language_interface, user.roles:authenticated, taxonomy_term_list:licenses, languages:language_url, user" are valid cache contexts. in assert() (line 31 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/Cache.php).

Debugging inside CacheContextsManager::validateTokens() I've seen that effectively the array that lists the "valid" cache contexts doesn't have that context, therefore the error is thrown.
$validContextTokens = [
  'cookies' => 0,
  'headers' => 1,
  'ip' => 2,
  'languages' => 3,
  'protocol_version' => 4,
  'request_format' => 5,
  'route' => 6,
  'route.is_admin' => 7,
  'route.menu_active_trails' => 8,
  'route.name' => 9,
  'session' => 10,
  'session.exists' => 11,
  'session.is_masquerading' => 12,
  'theme' => 13,
  'timezone' => 14,
  'url' => 15,
  'url.path' => 16,
  'url.path.is_front' => 17,
  'url.path.parent' => 18,
  'url.query_args' => 19,
  'url.query_args.pagers' => 20,
  'url.site' => 21,
  'user' => 22,
  'user.is_super_user' => 23,
  'user.node_grants' => 24,
  'user.permissions' => 25,
  'user.roles' => 26,
  'languages:language_interface' => TRUE,
  'languages:language_url' => TRUE,
  'user.roles:authenticated' => TRUE,
];

I guess I'm doing something wrong\missing something, because I've already used the above code for adding the cache context in other parts - e.g. preprocess - but it's first time trying to add into a form_alter. However I could not find anything specific on internet.
Any idea why I should do?

This is not a valid cache context because it is a cache tag.

Whups, very silly error :facepalm. I don't remember the expression, but it's the perfect case where I was looking into a specific point of the code instead of the big picture.
Thanks!
